# How to do Trim operation in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I need to trim a text that has been entered in a text box using Java Script
before saving it in DB in asp.net.

Thanks

Comment: How about trimming server-side to allow for users with JS disabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    String.prototype.trim = function() {
        return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
    }

    var text = "      fdsfsdf        ";
    text = text.trim();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a trim function to your toolset :

```
Function trim (str) {
    return str.replace(/^\s+/g,'').replace(/\s+$/g,'')
}
```

Ans use it like this :

```
var trimmed = str.trim();
```

Note that if you use jquery, you can use [the included trim function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/).

Answer (score 2):

```
function trim(stringToTrim) {
    return stringToTrim.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
}
function ltrim(stringToTrim) {
    return stringToTrim.replace(/^\s+/,"");
}
function rtrim(stringToTrim) {
    return stringToTrim.replace(/\s+$/,"");
}

// example of using trim, ltrim, and rtrim
var myString = " hello my name is ";
alert("*"+trim(myString)+"*");
alert("*"+ltrim(myString)+"*");
alert("*"+rtrim(myString)+"*");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to support IE <= 8, javascript already has `String.prototype.trim`:

```
" hello ".trim() //"hello";
```